# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Android SOAP Response Byte Array

Tags: android, arrays, out-of-memory

I have written a web service which returns `byte array`.

When I call the service from an android application, it gives me **out of memory error** on the line:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + WebMethodName, envelope);
```

On some mobile devices it works, but on some mobile devices (probably the devices having low RAM) it throws out of memory error.

Please suggest.

Update#2
@Rohit - Here is my code

```
public static void DownloadFile(String WebMethodName, String ServiceURL)
{
byte[] imgBytes=null;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, WebMethodName);

PropertyInfo NameProperty = new PropertyInfo();
NameProperty.setName("Name");
NameProperty.setValue("TEST");
NameProperty.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(NameProperty);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ServiceURL,100000);

try {
    //On below line I get OOM error

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + WebMethodName, envelope);
    final SoapPrimitive primitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    if (primitive == null)
    {
        imgBytes=null;
    }
    else
    {
        final String imgData = primitive.toString();

        if (imgData != "")
        {
            imgBytes = Base64.decode(imgData, Base64.DEFAULT);
            String s = new String(imgBytes);

            String filePath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/TestDirectory/Test.apk" ;

            File file = new File(filePath);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();

            BufferedOutputStream objectOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            objectOut.write(imgBytes);
            objectOut.close();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Log.w("ImgData", "Image data is null");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.w("ImgData", "Error :" + e.getMessage());
}

}
```

Update#3

@parik dhakan

I tried largeHeap="true" but got same error. Also I have read that it is not advisable to use largeHeap="true". 
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please provide your code to check the exact issuse.

Comment: @Rohit - I have added code in my question. Please check and revert.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<application android:largeHeap="true">
```

in your manifest